# Postgresql - Filter object array and extract required values in a json object

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table like below:

```
| data |
| -------------- |
| {"name":"a","tag":[{"type":"country","value":"US"}]} |
| {"name":"b","tag":[{"type":"country","value":"US"}]}, {"type":"country","value":"UK"}]} |
| {"name":"c","tag":[{"type":"gender","value":"male"}]} |
```

The goal is to extract all the value in "tag" array with "type" = "country" and aggregate them into a text array. The expected result is as follows:

```
| result         |
| -------------- |
| ["US"]         |
| ["US", "UK"]   |
| []             |
```

I've tried to expand the "tag" array and aggregate the desired result back; however, it requires a unique id to group up the results. Hence, I add a column with row number to serve as unique id. Here is what I've done:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS id, * INTO data_table_with_id FROM data_table;

SELECT ARRAY_AGG(tag_value) AS result
FROM (
    SELECT
        id, 
        json_array_elements("data"::json->'tag')->>'type' as tag_type,
        json_array_elements("data"::json->'tag')->>'value' as tag_value 
    FROM data_table_with_id
) tags 
WHERE tag_type = 'country' 
GROUP BY id;
```

Is it possible to use a single select to filter the object array and get the required  results?

Comment: The second line of your sample data is invalid JSON. Should the `UK` item go into the `tag` array?

Comment: Note that the use of `select ... into new_table` is discouraged in favour of the standard compliant `create new_table as select ....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily with a JSON path function:

```
select jsonb_path_query_array(data, '$.tag[*] ?(@.type == "country").value')
from data_table;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I'm looking for. Furthermore, the return type of this function is json array (jsonb), is there a method to cast the result to a text array (text[])?

Comment: No, there is no easy way from a JSON array to a native array. There are several workarounds - search this site. But the expected result in your question shows a JSON array, not a native text array